# How many values should one validate to achieve a desired confidence?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, validation, quality-control

If I have a set of 100 values which have been programmatically calculated and I would like to validate those calculations by performing them manually, how many manual calculations would I need to do to be 99% sure the programmatic calculations are all correct?

I'm not sure of the appropriate formula or the right way to think about this.

Edit: I believe the correct approach is to use the Wilson Approximation of the Binomial proportion confidence interval. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

This works out to ~150 trials to be 99% confident that the accurate calculation rate is between 95% and 100%.

Comment: What sense would it make to sample 150 values when you have only 100 total?

Comment: @whuber exactly. Seems that the lowest number of values to check in order to have a high confidence of accuracy is higher than what makes sense for this example

Comment: The problem is that your sampling is not Binomial: it's Hypergeometric.  But by discussing a Binomial solution, you are sending conflicting messages about what kind of situation you're in and what kind of sampling you have in mind.

Comment: @whuber that's true, thanks for that correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to think about this.

If you want to use the confidence interval approach, then you should also look at the "finite population correction" (Googling for that phrase results in several hits that look promising).

But your question was about the probability of all the 100 calculations being correct, whereas the confidence interval approach answers a little bit different question.  Your original question is more interesting (and less standard), so I will give some advice there.

One simple option is to consider the case where there is exactly 1 wrong calculation out of the 100 and you are going to check $n$ calculations out of the 100, chosen at random.  This is the simplest case (when not all are correct) mathematically, but would require the biggest sample to find with high confidence.  In this case if you chose 50 to check ($n=50$), then there is a 50% chance of finding the incorrect calculation, with $n=70$ there would be a 70% chance of getting the single incorrect calculation, etc.  So to be 99% sure you would need to check $n=99$ of the 100 calculations and find them all correct.

If you believe that a larger number will be incorrect (e.g. if they are not all correct, then at least 10 will be incorrect) then the similar probabilities can be calculated using the hypergeometric distribution.  For example with 10 mistakes and $n=30$ there is about a 2.3% chance that all the tested calculations will be correct.  At $n=36$ that percentage goes below 1%, so with $n=36$ you can be 99% confident/sure that there are no mistakes in the 100 (under the assumption that if there are any mistakes, then there will be at least 10).

An even better approach would be to use a Bayesian approach where you start with a prior on the probability of an error in each of the 100 cases, then work out the posterior probability given the number of manual checks that confirmed they were correct, then use that the estimate the probability of the remaining being correct.

All of this assumes of course that your manual checking is accurate (calculations that have been confirmed have 100% chance of being correct).

Comment: Thanks, well explained and makes sense. I see several resources on the Bayesian approach online, but are there any you recommend?

Comment: @ejkeep, I really like the book "Statistical Rethinking" by McElreath.  He has provided videos of his teaching classes based on the book, so you can get a whole intro course for free (just not the credits).